# Import Error (ModuleNotFound) in Python 3.7.6 while importing function of one python file to another in the same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 python (.py) files in the SAME directory, `DataLoader.py` and `main.py`. I want to access the function `Batch` defined in `DataLoader.py` from `main.py`.

I used this line in my `main.py` code:

```py
  from DataLoader import Batch
```

But still, I am getting the ModuleNotFound Error.

I am using Python 3.7.6, Anaconda Distribution and using Spyder as my IDE.

Comment: Can you edit the post and provide the whole error lines you are getting. That would be more helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you verified that your working directory is set to this same directory?

Comment: If your directory is missing __init__.py file, add it